# Ecto elixir query return

Tags: elixir, ecto

I so have this query I'm running that looks like this:

```
defp get(demand, offset) do
  IO.puts "demand/offset: #{demand}/#{offset}"
  events = C3poRepo.all(
    from t in C3poEvent,
      where: t.completed == 0,
      order_by: [asc: t.id],
      limit: ^demand,
      offset: ^offset
  )
  IO.puts "number of events: #{length(events)}"
  events
end
```

(sidenote: This is being run in a GenStage with 3 stages)

examining the database shows that I've got 271K rows that should be pulled page at a time. Demand in this case is 1200, and the offset is 0. For the sake of testing I set the offset manually to 0 to just grab the next 1200 rows of completed = 0 rows.

What I expect to see is:

> demand/offset: 1200/0
>   number of events: **1200**

What I'm seeing is:

> demand/offset: 1200/0
>  
>   number of events: **20**

Anyone have any ideas as to why I'm only getting 20 events back? Is this perhaps related to what events really is as opposed to what I'm thinking of as a list of the records?

Comment: Does your database have > 1200 rows with `t.completed == 0`?

Comment: Yes, it has 271,388 rows that match the query.

Comment: Can you confirm by checking the output of `IO.inspect C3poRepo.one(from t in C3poEvent, where: t.completed == 0, select: count(t.id))`?

Comment: That indeed returns 20. I guess that means that the "number of events: 20" is reasonable, but I still don't understand where the 20 comes from. When I run "select count(*) from events where completed = 0" (using dbeaver) I get  271K

Comment: You can see what query was executed by Ecto in the logs.

Comment: I found my issue. I had the wrong table referred to in my event model schema. I only found this because you had me inspect the query output in my logs, so thank you very much :)